# JS: addEventListener to the dynamically created DOM objects, which delete parentNode

Tags: javascript, html-table, row

I am trying to do this: perform a simple calculation with a few user-inputted numbers, and then on a click add the calculation to the table in a new row. Table should have three columns, for three numbers. Everything is fine, but I am stuck at this: how to add option for user to delete some of the rows?

So, this would be the html structure:

```
        <tbody id="tableBody">
            <tr id="row8"> <!-- In js this is ("row" + i) -->
                <td class="dimA"></td>
                <td class="dimB"></td>
                <td class="area"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="del8"></td> <!-- In js this is ("del" + i) -->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

So, the tr element is created by javascript, and the i in the ids is incremented after every addition. I need to be able to delete entire row when user checks the check box. I know the way of doing it with addEventListener, but how to do it with unknown number of items?

Here is Javascript:

```
function dodajNaListu(eventInfo) {
    if (dimA & dimB !== 0) {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        tr.id = "row" + i;

        var td1 = document.createElement("td");
        td1.className = "dimA";
        var A = document.createTextNode(dimA);
        td1.appendChild(A);

        var td2 = document.createElement("td");
        td2.className = "dimB";
        var B = document.createTextNode(dimB);
        td2.appendChild(B);

        var td3 = document.createElement("td");
        td3.className = "area";
        var P = document.createTextNode(rezultat);
        td3.appendChild(P);

        var td4 = document.createElement("td");
        var chck1 = document.createElement("input");
        chck1.id = "del" + i;
        chck1.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        td4.appendChild(chck1);

        tr.appendChild(td1);
        tr.appendChild(td2);
        tr.appendChild(td3);
        tr.appendChild(td4);
        document.getElementById("tableBody").appendChild(tr);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I am an obvious novice in this area. And no, I am not using jQuery. This is actually a Windows 8.1 app I need for my work.

Comment: Please expose the relevant Js part (row creation)

Comment: Added Javascript (row creation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. Here is jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/sez1bwL3/

I added an event listener to every check box created within function dodajNaListu that calls this function:

```
function delRow() {
    var current = window.event.srcElement;
    while ((current = current.parentElement) && current.tagName != "TR");
    current.parentElement.removeChild(current);
}
```

Here is link to a web page where I found my answer:
http://www.joegarrepy.com/tableaddrow_jscript.htm

Have a great day.